# How many possible solutions for 6 wires?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, logic, functions

Imagine 2 sets of 6 wires. How would I find how many possible connections there are?

Every wire must be used to be considered a connection.

```
//1st set
ABCDEF
GHIJKL

//2nd set
ABCDEF
HGIJKL

//visual layout of situation
0 1
0 1
0 1
0 1
0 1
0 1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure what you meant by the sets of wires, but assuming you have two stacks of six pieces of wires, like:

- 1st: A,B,C,D,E,F
- 2nd: G,H,I,J,K,L

Then A can be connected to 6 pieces (G,H,I,J,K,L), B to 5 (G,H,I,J,K,L except for one) and so on, so the answer could be 6!=720.

Comment: I believe that's what we're looking for... what's the correct term for 6!? Like if I was to say it

Comment: @bradenkeith - factorial, see e.g. on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial)

Comment: @Braden: Also look up permutations.